# Decided the order of the groupby output?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

After the groupby, the output order of the group is pre-decided. In the following case,  the order is A, AAA, B, BBB.

Is there a way to customize this order? I want to order to be AAA,A,BBB,B. I might want it in other orders as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
data=pd.DataFrame({'Rating':['A','AAA','B','BBB','A','AAA','B','BBB'],
                  'Score':[2,4,5,6,2,4,5,6,]})
t=data.groupby('Rating', sort=False)['Score'].mean()
t
Rating
A      2
AAA    4
B      5
BBB    6
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the order returned by groupby/mean (save what's possible with the `sort` parameter). However, it easy to change the order after the fact using `reindex`:

```
In [24]: data.groupby('Rating', sort=False)['Score'].mean().reindex(['AAA', 'A', 'BBB', 'B'])
Out[24]: 
Rating
AAA    4
A      2
BBB    6
B      5
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

---

Alternatively, you can control the order returned by `groupby/mean` by changing `Ratings` to a `Categorical`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Rating':['A','AAA','B','BBB','A','AAA','B','BBB'],
                  'Score':[2,4,5,6,2,4,5,6,]})
data['Rating'] = pd.Categorical(data['Rating'], categories=['AAA','A','BBB','B'], 
                                ordered=True)
result = data.groupby('Rating', sort=False)['Score'].mean()
print(result)
```

yields

```
Rating
AAA    4
A      2
BBB    6
B      5
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort=False` just means that it's not guaranteed to be sorted (it may be ordered). My recollection is that this is in the "seen order", but again that's no guaranteed.

To sort the output of a groupby, just do the sort after (by the index):

```
In [11]: t.sort_index()
Out[11]:
Rating
A      2
AAA    4
B      5
BBB    6
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hmmm, I see this doesn't sort into `AAA,A,BBB,B` but I'm not sure how you can do that without reindexing manually (like @unutbu's answer).